# List adapter fragment

Tags: android, list, pdf, view, adapter

Something wents wrong with this line on my fragment

```
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
```

I tried to getactivity , getview etc... Nothing works , so i don't know how to do this.
The code works good on an activity

Comment: use `getListView().setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the Adapter bad

Change

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
```

to

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
```

Comment: Waw , very amaze , such response ! Thanks a lot , awesome !